# If a commutative ring with identity is the sum of two ideals, then their product is equal to their intersection.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

My problem is to prove exactly as the title says; particularly if I+J=R for some commutative ring R with identity and ideals I and J of the ring R, then IJ = I ∩ J.

I know already that IJ is an ideal in I ∩ J. I tried supposing that there is some element k of I ∩ J which is not in IJ, and from the hypothesis it's clear there's some x in I and y in J so that x + y = k. I know that k is in IJ if some set of products $x_i y_i$ for $i = 1, 2, 3, ..., n$ sum to k, but I don't quite know how to arrive at this contradiction from the rest.

Comment: You're right, sorry; it's also commutative. I forgot that part.

Comment: The important thing is that $1 = i+j$ with $i \in I,\, j \in J$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is immediate that $IJ \subset I \cap J$. For the reverse direction, take $x \in I \cap J$. Since $I+J=R$, there exist elements $a \in I$ and $b \in J$ such that $1=a+b$. Now, $x = x  1 = xa+xb$ and $xa, xb \in I J$. Hence $x \in IJ$ and this proves that $IJ = I\cap J$.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like forgetting the ring was commutative with identity was the source of all my problems.

Answer (score 0):

To prove $IJ\supset I\cap J$, use the fact $I+J=R$. Because of $I+J=R$, there exists $i\in I$ and $j\in J$ satisfy that $i+j=1$, where $1$ is the multiplicative identity of the ring. If $x\in I\cap J$, then $1x1=ixi+ixj+jxi+jxj\in I\cap J$. Since $I$ and $J$ are ideal, we get $xi,xj\in J$ and $jx\in I$ so $i(xi)+i(xj)+j(xi)+(jx)j\in IJ$.

Comment: Why $i(xi) \in IJ$? I can only see why $i(xi) \in I$.

Comment: @lisyarus This is because $x\in J$ and an ideal is closed under the right scalar multiplication